# Calendar Programming Project in C. Too complicated for this newbie

Tags: c, calendar

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
    int numdays, month, day, year = 1;


    while (year > 0)`enter code here`
    {
        printf("Enter Month:  ");
        scanf("%d", &month);
        printf("Enter Day:  ");
        scanf("%d", &day);
        printf("Enter Year:  ");
        scanf("%d", &year);

        numdays = ((year - 1) * 365 + ((year - 1) / 4) - ((year - 1) / 100) + ((year - 1) / 400)); // how many days including exceptions

        if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))        //check if leapyear
        {
            if (month = 1)                          // January 
                numdays = numdays;
            if (month = 2)                          // February 
                numdays = numdays + 31;
            if (month = 3)                          // March 
                numdays = numdays + 28 + 31 + 1;
            if (month = 4)                          // April 
                numdays = numdays + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
            if (month = 5)                          // May 
                numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
            if (month = 6)                          // June 
                numdays = numdays + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
            if (month = 7)                          // July 
                numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
            if (month = 8)                          // August 
                numdays = numdays + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
            if (month = 9)                          // September 
                numdays = numdays + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
            if (month = 10)                         // October                      
                numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
            if (month = 11)                         // November
                numdays = numdays + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
            if (month = 12)                         // December
                numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (month = 1)                          // January 
                numdays = numdays;
            if (month = 2)                          // February 
                numdays = numdays + 31;
            if (month = 3)                          // March 
                numdays = numdays + 28 + 31;
            if (month = 4)                          // April 
                numdays = numdays + 31 + 28 + 31;
            if (month = 5)                          // May 
                numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
            if (month = 6)                          // June 
                numdays = numdays + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
            if (month = 7)                          // July 
                numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
            if (month = 8)                          // August 
                numdays = numdays + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
            if (month = 9)                          // September 
                numdays = numdays + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
            if (month = 10)                         // October                      
                numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
            if (month = 11)                         // November
                numdays = numdays + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
            if (month = 12)                         // December
                numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
            {
                printf("%d %d %d\n", month, day, year);
            }
            int daycode = numdays % 7;
            switch (daycode)
            {
            case 0:
                printf("Sunday\n");
                break;

            case 1:
                printf("Monday\n");
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("Tuesday\n");
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("Wednesday\n");
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("Thursday\n");
                break;

            case 5:
                printf("Friday\n");
                break;

            case 6:
                printf("Saturday\n");
                break;

            default: printf("unexpected error (daycode case) daycode = %d", daycode);
                break;`enter code here`
            }

        }

    }

}
```

What I need to do is get the output to read what the day would be on the given date input by the user. However, I don't understand why my month is being locked at 12 for input. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The first thing you probably want to do is change your `if(month = x)` to `if(month == x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by MrPickles, the main problem is that you are mixing up the assignment operator `=` with the comparison operator `==`. The former (`=`) sets the variable on the left to whatever is on the right, while `==` checks if the right hand and left hand sides are equal. Your last if statement is *setting* month to 12 instead of checking if it's 12.

Another big problem is that your code to print out the solution is inside your else statement, so it doesn't run at all if it's a leap year. Make sure to move it out.

Finally, you never actually use the *day* of the month in your code. You need to put in something like `numdays+=day;`.

Other than that, you could make the code much shorter, but I think it's right besides that.

Comment: As a side comment, you are not actually using anything from the `math.h` header, so you can drop `#include <math.h>` if you like.

Comment: Thanks all! that month thing and adding day to my numdays declaration made it work perfectly! I appreciate the help! =)